# Wireframing tool with customizable UI components and real time collaboration

Tags: wireframe, tools

I work for a very large fortune 500 company. In order to improve the development process, I would like to allow employees to wireframe using components that already have the companies' brand and look and feel, as opposed to apply graphic design after finishing the wireframes (or detailed design) or use graphic guidelines only when development starts.
Although there are disadvantages to do colorful and highly detailed wireframes, I believe this will shorten the graphic design phase.

I considered iRise annd Axure but they are too complex to learn for people who are developers, system analysts and projects managers, not UX professionals. Other popular tools like UXPin, Mockflow and others do not support customizing components for re-use.

What wireframing/prototyping tool would you recommend that supports this need?
It must have a quick learning curve, customizable UI components library and real time collaboration.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how your developers, system analysts and projects managers would be working with wireframes?

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for software / books / papers  / etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution that involves a white board and taking pictures. Taking a couple of steps back if you aims is to understand how your stakeholders or other team members understand the problem then a one to one session where you work collaboratively on a white board will be more useful than interfaces put together by developers and project managers you'll only have to throw away.

It is the thoughts that the members of the team have rather than the implementations they come up with that are important and there is a danger that non UX team members will become wed to a certain way of doing things if they produce actual wireframes. Doing it collaboratively allows the ideas to flow develop much quicker without the need for long wire-framing sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my only choice in your case will be :

[**HotGloo**](http://www.hotgloo.com/)

What does it offer (in addition to all the common features) :

- Small or even no learning curve , for anyone with computer experience .
- Full list of ready made ui elements
- You can customize your own elements or use what others have created .

Comment: Also worth looking at http://www.flairbuilder.com/features/wireframe-components.php as another option to HotGloo - hope this helps